# asynchronous request of images by url for scrollview ios

Tags: ios, asynchronous, uiscrollview

I wanted to know how it is possible to make asynchronous request of images, and display them in a scroll view in a way that I can scroll the images without making requests for each images. I read some threads that gave me some ideas, so I think that I have to stock the urls in an array, and then I don't know what to do. If someone can explain to me ? or have a concrete idea on how to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSScreencast has a video that does something similar. It is also a good video to learn about blocks too.

http://nsscreencast.com/episodes/10-fun-with-blocks

Comment: Thank you ! it helps me to understant and I did the asynchronous method in my app :)

Answer (score 0):

in order to load images asynchronously there are many options. The best approach is to create a different thread and fetch the url.

Sometimes its better to used tested and trusted apis available. I will suggest you to use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

This will not only help you to load images asynchronously but also provides the caching mechanism. Which you will later or sooner user in you app development.

Its easy to use. Happy Coding :)